# Some spreadsheet cells not updated before trigger function sends email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet which extracts and accumulates all the required data from other 6 spreadsheets using Vmerge and Query formulas and all the consolidated data will be converted to pdf and emaild to mail ids using trigger event.

Here begins the problem every time the attachment mail posted consist all the headers and other format, but the data which is extracted does not appear. It seems to appear like `-` to open the same spreadsheet,  after a while all the `-` (hyphens) are replaced by the data / Hope all the data updates after a while of opening the spreadsheet.

[link for sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AjkkHlm3kCphdDB3MURnOUlmajZGem8taTJkSGU1emc)

[image: screenshot]

Can anyone direct me to make this issue sorted out.

For this solution should be -> all the data should be updated and then the email script should work; or either it should update before emailing script starts.

Or any other better ideas are appreciated.

Comment: This script you mentioned, is it a Google Apps Script?

Comment: Yes, Its an apps script. Have you gone through

Comment: Were you able to `getLastRow` working as well?

Comment: Yes i have done it. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some spreadsheet formulas, like `ImportRange` and `ImportXml` (and also Apps Script custom formulas) are only evaluated when there's someone logged in the spreadsheet. It's like these functions need an account to be evaluated from, for example, in `importRange` the account logged in must have access to the range being imported, if you share this spreadsheet with someone but not the `importRange` source, when this person is viewing this spreadsheet, the `importRange` function will not work (well, unless you're also in the spreadsheet and the formulas have already been evaluated).

Bottom line is, you can't have this formulas and use a script triggered on time-driven (or other trigger that does not require someone logged in) and expect the script to be able to read this data.

The workaround though is quite simple. Do what the `importRange` function does inside your script! e.g.

```js
var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('source-spreadsheet-key');
var data = source.getSheetByName('List').getRange('I6:AT500').getValues();
//then save it somewhere
var s = Spreadsheet.getActive().getSheetByName('hidden-import');
s.getRange('I6:AT500').setValues(data);
SpreadsheetApp.flush(); //force the data to be written
//so all the other formulas on your spreadsheet get updated with the new data
```

All your "logic" formulas, like `query` and `vmerge`, which are difficult for the script to mimic, can be left on the spreadsheet, but reference this "hidden-import" sheet I just invented instead of nesting `importRange` directly.

**[edit]**

To copy only non-empty rows do like this:

```js
var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById('source-spreadsheet-key').
  getSheetByName('List').getDataRange().getValues();
Spreadsheet.getActive().getSheetByName('hidden-import').
  getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
```

Comment: Thank you for the support & suggestion. For same can you guide me with a script to copy only not empty rows. as the script is copying all including empty ones also.

Comment: I've included this in my answer.

Comment: Thank you once again, i was just lost in trying to extract from a specified (first column&row  to column+lastrow)  e.g i7:AT+{Last row}. But i was not able to make it. can you pls help me out.

Comment: From the snippet I pasted you should be able to do this yourself. What you're asking are not doubts anymore, you just want that I do it for you. You should read the Apps Script tutorials and documentation to find out how to do it yourself: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles

Comment: Thank you for every thing you have done for me Mr.Henrique Abreu. I hope you have understood the my query. i have tried it but my doubt was how to extract last row number before the line 'code' var data = source.getSheetByName('List').getRange('I6:AT500').getValues(); is executed. this I have only request. if you are willing or not willing i am grateful and thankful to you for your deed. And please note that i am not insisting you, as per my knowledge i am just asking help for this. I am extremely sorry if i hurt you with my english.

Comment: Ok, sorry for being harsh. Take a look at the docs here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_sheet#getLastRow (by the way, I see that you never mark any answer to your questions on stackoverflow as accepted, you should do it when you feel you got a good answer, voting is also important).

Comment: Thank you very much for guiding me. To be honest till now i never knew  abut "voting", for now i would definitely answer and vote. As answered earlier on extracting non empty rows. i have tried but the script is copying all data including blank rows. could you please verify it once again for me. Thanks in advance

Comment: With your guidance, i have voted to all those who have helped me in my scripting work. Thank you once again.